# How to exclude all letters except for a specific word - regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have this regex

```
[^a-z]*
```

that excludes all letters/words. But how to redo it so that it still excludes all letters/words except for specified, by us, word.

Comment: Is it just one word, or could it be multiple words?

Comment: Just one for the moment, but if you got a solution for multiple go ahead, maybe in the future we will make use of it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put the list of words you want to include as alternates, i.e. `word1|word2|[^a-z]*`

Comment: Thank you very much for immediate answer @Steve